# Why I am getting syntax error in selenium relative xpath?

Tags: selenium

I am an absolute beginner in programming and trying to locate an element from a webtool using Selenium and Python. I had to look for relative path since absolute path DIV value keep changing. Using ChroPath I found the relative path.

Absolute path is:
/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[31]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div

here element which is at div[31] sometimes becomes div[30] or div[32]. I searched web and found that I need to look for relative path instead of absolute path.

So I tried relative path method.

HTML line:

//div class="vp-btnc-text" xpath="1">CS-CORE Capacity Planning

Relative path provided by Chropath:
//div[contains(text(),'CS-CORE Capacity Planning')]

My line in code that I am trying is :
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),'CS-CORE Capacity Planning')]').click()

Error that I am getting is:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),'CS-CORE Capacity Planning')]')
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Need help to resolve the issue please.

Comment: Never Mind please. I found the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add an explicit wait time or implicit wait
Example:

```
WebElement messageElement = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("AnotherElementBeforeThisElementIsLoaded")) );
```

or implicit wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Also,

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath(//divclass='vp-btnc-text' xpath='1'>CS-CORE Capacity Planning));
```

Sometime,you need to change double quotes to single quotes for xpath.

Comment: Good!, you can avoid it next time.

Comment: Thanks @Soni Vashisht. I have to add explicit wait later on in this code at various steps once my code is ready.

Answer (score 0):

paste the xpath inside double quotes like below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'CS-CORE Capacity Planning')]").click()
```